# Query String Variables Exist, but $_GET is empty

Tags: php

I've developed a website for a client on my development server, and pushed it to the production server.  On both sites, the URL is something like `http://www.siteurl.com/blogs/?m=09&y=2012`

On the development server, if I `var_dump($_GET)`, I get the values I expect.

On the production server, if I `var_dump($_GET)`, I get an empty array.

I'd post the `phpinfo()` if it helps, I don't even know what settings could possibly cause this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please check your website; I get a 404 error.

Comment: That's not the actual URL, just an example of what I was doing.  I'd rather not post the actual URL.

Comment: Okay, I thought I would see your code there.  Anyway, you are using and `&`, rather than `&amp;`, which might affect the interpretation.

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules on one that aren't on the other? Total long shot.

Comment: Doesn't PHP have some setting to disable passing variables through the URL?

Comment: @LOLapalooza - you might want to use 'example.com' for fake urls; it's more obvious it's an example (and guaranteed to be an invalid, since 'example.com' is reserved for this usage).

Comment: Do you have Apache rewrite rules that might not be appending the querystring ([QSA] flag)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue.

See this forum discussion: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/734/_get-empty/p1

```
Solved replacing this:
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

for this:
RewriteRule .* index.php?$0 [PT,L]
```

Add New Rule to .htaccess. It will works

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z]+$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I don't have that exactly, but something similar.  My htaccess skills are not very good.  What should I change here? `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdir/index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 2):

As I was saying above, you need the `QSA` flag (read "query string append") to pass the query string to PHP:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /subdir/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /subdir/index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```