# Google OAuth2 - authorization code request resulting in a redirect loop after consent

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have written a custom OAuth2 code implementation in php for my site.
Users can sign with their Facebook, Google or Yahoo accounts.

While Facebook and Yahoo sign in is working perfectly. I am having an issue with Google sign in. After providing my consent on the google consent screen i am redirected back to the consent screen.

I used persist logs in firefox inspector network tab and below is the screen shot. (My comments in red)

[image: Authorization code is received but immediately redirected to Authorization url]

In the response headers, there is a location header redirecting back to the authorization url. The only time this location header is used, if the $_GET code is not set (See my code below)

```
} elseif (! isset($_GET['code'])) {

    // This shouldn't execute after consent is provided,
    // since $_GET['code'] is already set 
    // No authorization code then get one
    $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->get('state');
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit;
}
```

Below is the code i am using to instantiate the class. I use the same code for Yahoo and Facebook. And both have no such issues.

I haven't been able to figure out why the redirect is happening.

**/******* UPDATE *********/**

I tried dumping the $_GET variables to a file and found it empty. So the query string is set but $_GET is empty. I checked stackoverflow and found this link - [Query String Variables Exist, but $_GET is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714233/query-string-variables-exist-but-get-is-empty)

I'm not sure why this isn't happening with Yahoo and Facebook Oauth but here is my .htaccess. I'm not sure how to use the QSA flag to append the query string. I get an internal server error with the below line.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !(robots\.txt|\.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|woff?2)) [NC]
  RewriteRule . index.php [L, QSA]
```

**/******* UPDATE *********/**

To further debug, I actually tried dumping $_GET and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']  variable to a file at various points in my code to see if i accidentally unset the GET variable.

For Facebook login which uses the same code, both query string and GET variables are set right from the entry point i.e index.php.

For google login, query string is present but GET variables are not set anywhere. That is curious. The only other place i can look at is htaccess and i can't notice anything that should selectively remove get variables from google-login path :(

Any suggestions would be really helpful

**/******* FINAL UPDATE *********/**

I put together this hack to reset the GET variables. I use it only for the Google login and with the GET variables set everything is working now. Hopefully a temporary solution.

```
// if GET is empty and query string exists
if (empty($_GET) && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') !== false) {
    parse_str(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $_GET);
}
```

Comment: In your `RewriteCond` shouldn't `%{THE_REQUEST}` rather be `%{REQUEST_URI} `?

Comment: So i change THE_REQUEST to REQUEST_URI and everything else remains the same? Please also have a look at the latest edit updates. If you can suggest something.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but `THE_REQUEST` looks strange in this context because it contains the full HTTP request (e.g. `"GET /index.php HTTP/1.1"`). That makes it unlikely that the `RewriteRule` is triggered at all. But maybe it hasn't anything to do with your problem, I didn't test it myself.